# Setting up a home server but don't know what to call what I'm doing to ask for help

Tags: proxy, vpn, email, file-sharing, hosting

So I have a decent home server that I'd Like to do a couple things with:

1. Host a website ( I know how to do this so I'm not worried about this )
2. Create remote user storage - I'd like to make something where I could Log into a VPN(?) and it give me account specific storage, I'd like to be able to work from my files at home and back my linux computers up to this server, Maybe in the form of images? but how would I do this?
3. As Part of a VPN I'd like it to serve as a proxy for remote devices and an email server.

which packages should I use to achieve these goals? Is there a name for what I'm trying to do and is this a common thing to do?